# R fast.read.fwf colClasses ='character'

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to read fixed width file with `colClasses ='character'` but somehow still the numeric columns with leading zeroes are truncated

Can you tell me a solution to how to retain leading zeroes while reading `fast.read.fwf` pls

Syntax used:

```
T1<- fast.read.fwf(file=q.txt, width = (c(3,19,8,15)),
                   col.names=c("v1", "v2","v3","v4"), colClasses = "character")
```

Comment: Hard to say without you giving a working example (e.g. a fragment of the file, the code you use to read in). What happens when you try `read.fwf` instead of `fast.read.fwf`?

Comment: Read.fwf takes it forever. I have almost 3 million data

Comment: Take first hundred lines and use this for testing. Or give us first ten lines. Or make a mockup example.